# oracle apex arabic characters not displaying properly in csv export

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex-20.1

I have an Interactive Report with column having arabic Characters displaying well in the Report , however i am exporting the Reports into csv but the arabic characters turns to `?????` in csv file , Any suggestions or workaround i may follow either at Interactive Report level or query level or this something csv don't support.

Comment: what is the characterset of the database ? and which language do you have in the PC you are using the browser ?

Comment: `NLS_CHARACTERSET = AL32UTF8`

Comment: `NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET = AL16UTF16`

Comment: I am downloading csv from IR in Chrome browser

Comment: are you using download csv from the menu actions in the IR ??

Comment: Yes I am using download csv option from Action Menu

Comment: that could be the reason. Normally the java script object in charge of the download process will not take in consideration the CHARACTERSET of the database, instead it will use the encoding in client side. I can provide you an example on how to create a button to download the report in the right characterset, but out of the actions menu, in this case using a button . If you want it , I can publish it as answer

Comment: Yes really appreciate if you can share as answer

Answer (score 2):

I am not entirely sure, but I think the problem might happen because the Java script function associated with Actions Menu --> Download might not take in consideration the encoding on database side, rather than the one on client side.

Normally, when I want to control the export to csv from a page, I disable the actions menu to avoid that the user can do it using that menu, instead I prefer to create a PL/SQL procedure to be triggered by an application express process.

How to do that ?

### **Download CSV File Using PL/SQL Procedure and Application Process in Oracle Apex**

In order to do this , follow the instructions:

**1.Create a PL/SQL Procedure**

Create a database procedure which will return the CSV as CLOB data.

```
create or replace procedure tab_to_csv(o_Clobdata OUT CLOB) IS 
  l_Blob         BLOB; 
  l_Clob         CLOB; 
  
BEGIN 
 
  Dbms_Lob.Createtemporary(Lob_Loc => l_Clob, 
                           Cache   => TRUE, 
                           Dur     => Dbms_Lob.Call); 
  SELECT Clob_Val 
    INTO l_Clob 
    FROM (SELECT Xmlcast(Xmlagg(Xmlelement(e, 
                                           Col_Value || Chr(13) || 
                                           Chr(10))) AS CLOB) AS Clob_Val, 
                 COUNT(*) AS Number_Of_Rows 
            FROM (SELECT 'your columns for the header split by the separator' AS Col_Value 
                    FROM Dual 
                  UNION ALL 
                  SELECT col1||',' ||col2||','|| col3||','|| col4||','|| col5||','|| col6 as Col_Value 
                    FROM (SELECT col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6 from yourtable))); 
 
  o_Clobdata := l_Clob; 
EXCEPTION 
  WHEN OTHERS THEN 
    NULL; 
END;
/
```

You can adapt that procedure the way you want. I use header, so that is the reason for the first select. In my example, the separator was `,` , but you can use another one if you like, or even use a parameter for it instead.

**2.Create an Application Process in Oracle Apex**

In Oracle Apex, click on the `Shared Components --> Application Process` and then click on the Create button. Then follow these steps:

[image]

Then press next and put the following code

```
DECLARE
    L_BLOB           BLOB;
    L_CLOB           CLOB;
    L_DEST_OFFSET    INTEGER := 1;
    L_SRC_OFFSET     INTEGER := 1;
    L_LANG_CONTEXT   INTEGER := DBMS_LOB.DEFAULT_LANG_CTX;
    L_WARNING        INTEGER;
    L_LENGTH         INTEGER;
BEGIN

    -- create new temporary BLOB
    DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY(L_BLOB, FALSE);
    
    --get CLOB
    tab_to_csv( L_CLOB);
    
    -- tranform the input CLOB into a BLOB of the desired charset
    DBMS_LOB.CONVERTTOBLOB( DEST_LOB     => L_BLOB,
                            SRC_CLOB     => L_CLOB,
                            AMOUNT       => DBMS_LOB.LOBMAXSIZE,
                            DEST_OFFSET  => L_DEST_OFFSET,
                            SRC_OFFSET   => L_SRC_OFFSET,
                            BLOB_CSID    => NLS_CHARSET_ID('WE8MSWIN1252'),
                            LANG_CONTEXT => L_LANG_CONTEXT,
                            WARNING      => L_WARNING
                          );

    -- determine length for header
    L_LENGTH := DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(L_BLOB);  

    -- first clear the header
    HTP.FLUSH;
    HTP.INIT;

    -- create response header
    OWA_UTIL.MIME_HEADER( 'text/csv', FALSE, 'AL32UTF8');
    
    HTP.P('Content-length: ' || L_LENGTH);
    HTP.P('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="yourfile.csv"');
    HTP.P('Set-Cookie: fileDownload=true; path=/');

    OWA_UTIL.HTTP_HEADER_CLOSE;

    -- download the BLOB
    WPG_DOCLOAD.DOWNLOAD_FILE( L_BLOB );

    -- stop APEX
   -- APEX_APPLICATION.STOP_APEX_ENGINE;
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      DBMS_LOB.FREETEMPORARY(L_BLOB);
      RAISE;
END;
```

After that click on the Next button and on the next screen click on the Create button to finish the wizard. Your application process has been created.

**3.Create a Button on a Page in Oracle Apex**

Now open a page in Page designer in Oracle Apex in which you want to add a button to download the CSV file.

Then do the right-click on the Region and click on the option Create Button.

Set the Action to Redirect to URL.

Paste the following URL in the URL target.

```
f?p=&APP_ID.:0:&SESSION.:APPLICATION_PROCESS=download_emp_csv:NO
```

Notice that we are calling the application process download_emp_csv, we just created in the second step.

Now save the changes and run the page. On click of the button, the CSV file will be download.